# How to save variables at start of script for use later if script needs to be re-run due to errors or bad user input

Tags: bash, github, ffmpeg

I have a script that uses GitHub's API to get the latest version number of the repositories that I am trying to download and then compile.

Due to the fact that without using a specialized token from GitHub you are only allowed 50 API calls a day vs the 5000 a day with the API user token.

I want to be able to parse all of the repositories and grab the version numbers that my script will then import into the code up front so in case someone who accidentally cancels the build in the middle of it (for who knows what reasons) wont have to eat up their 50 day API call allowance.

Essentially, store each repo's version number, if the user then needs to rerun the script and version numbers that have been saved so far will be skipped (thus eliminating an API call) and any numbers that are still needing to be sourced will be called and then stored for used in the script.

I am kinda of lost for a method on how to go about this.

Maybe some sort of external file can be generated?

So what my script does is it builds FFmpeg from source code and all of the external libraries that you can link to it are also built from their latest source code.

The code calls the function `git_ver_fn` and passes arguments to it which are parsed inside the function and directed to another functions `git_1_fn or git_2_fn` which passed those parsed arguments that have been passed on to the CURL command which changes the URL based on the arguments passed. It uses the `jq` command to capture the GitHub `version number` and `download link` for the `tar.gz` file.

It is the version number I am and trying to figure out the best way to store in case the script fails and has to be rerun, which will eat up all of the 50 APT limit that GitHub imposes without a token. I can't post my token in the script because GitHub deactivates it and thus the users will be SOL if they need to run the script more than once.

```
curl_timeout='5'

git_1_fn()
{
    # SCRAPE GITHUB WEBSITE FOR LATEST REPO VERSION
    github_repo="$1"
    github_url="$2"

    if curl_cmd="$(curl -m "$curl_timeout" -sSL "https://api.github.com/repos/$github_repo/$github_url")"; then
        g_ver="$(echo "$curl_cmd" | jq -r '.[0].name')"
        g_ver="${g_ver#v}"
        g_ssl="$(echo "$curl_cmd" | jq -r '.[0].name')"
        g_ssl="${g_ssl#OpenSSL }"
        g_pkg="$(echo "$curl_cmd" | jq -r '.[0].name')"
        g_pkg="${g_pkg#pkg-config-}"
        g_url="$(echo "$curl_cmd" | jq -r '.[0].tarball_url')"
    fi
}

git_2_fn()
{
    videolan_repo="$1"
    videolan_url="$2"
    if curl_cmd="$(curl -m "$curl_timeout" -sSL "https://code.videolan.org/api/v4/projects/$videolan_repo/repository/$videolan_url")"; then
        g_ver="$(echo "$curl_cmd" | jq -r '.[0].commit.id')"
        g_sver="$(echo "$curl_cmd" | jq -r '.[0].commit.short_id')"
        g_ver1="$(echo "$curl_cmd" | jq -r '.[0].name')"
        g_ver1="${g_ver1#v}"
    fi
}

git_ver_fn()
{
    local v_flag v_tag url_tag

    v_url="$1"
    v_tag="$2"

    if [ -n "$3" ]; then v_flag="$3"; fi

    if [ "$v_flag" = 'B' ] && [  "$v_tag" = '2' ]; then
        url_tag='git_2_fn' gv_url='branches'
    fi

    if [ "$v_flag" = 'X' ] && [  "$v_tag" = '5' ]; then
        url_tag='git_5_fn'
    fi

    if [ "$v_flag" = 'T' ] && [  "$v_tag" = '1' ]; then
        url_tag='git_1_fn' gv_url='tags'
    elif [ "$v_flag" = 'T' ] && [  "$v_tag" = '2' ]; then
        url_tag='git_2_fn' gv_url='tags'
    fi

    if [ "$v_flag" = 'R' ] && [  "$v_tag" = '1' ]; then
        url_tag='git_1_fn'; gv_url='releases'
    elif [ "$v_flag" = 'R' ] && [  "$v_tag" = '2' ]; then
        url_tag='git_2_fn'; gv_url='releases'
    fi

    case "$v_tag" in
        2)          url_tag='git_2_fn';;
    esac

    "$url_tag" "$v_url" "$gv_url" 2>/dev/null
}

# begin source code building
git_ver_fn 'freedesktop/pkg-config' '1' 'T'
if build 'pkg-config' "$g_pkg"; then
    download "https://pkgconfig.freedesktop.org/releases/$g_ver.tar.gz" "$g_ver.tar.gz"
    execute ./configure --silent --prefix="$workspace" --with-pc-path="$workspace"/lib/pkgconfig/ --with-internal-glib
    execute make -j "$cpu_threads"
    execute make install
    build_done 'pkg-config' "$g_pkg"
fi

git_ver_fn 'yasm/yasm' '1' 'T'
if build 'yasm' "$g_ver"; then
    download "https://github.com/yasm/yasm/releases/download/v$g_ver/yasm-$g_ver.tar.gz" "yasm-$g_ver.tar.gz"
    execute ./configure --prefix="$workspace"
    execute make -j "$cpu_threads"
    execute make install
    build_done 'yasm' "$g_ver"
fi
```

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. What you are asking seems to amount to "how do I write stuff to a text file and read it back."

Comment: I'm sorry, if I could have done this myself I wouldn't have asked. Advice is a great thing to have. And that doesn't mean for one second that writing stuff to a text file is the best or only way of doing something like this, That is why I am reaching out for ideas.

Comment: I have not visited your Github script and most visitors here won't; try to put the essential code (but only that) in your question. Based on your stated requirements, I can't see why you would reach for anything more complex than a text file. If you need concurrent access, maybe a simple database.

Comment: This is an XY problem.  Just auth your github requests and you won't have a rate limit problem most likely.  https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#rate-limiting I see rate limits quite a lot higher thant what you're describing.  60 per *hour* even for unauthenticated requests. there are few compelling reasons, if any, not to authenticate your requests, and if you do, you'll be able to make thousands an hour.

Comment: I cant post my script with the API token in it so the users will have to modify the script with their own auth ID if they want to up their API allowance.  There are so many repos that running the script twice will break the API limit. I am going to post some code on here so people will be more inclined to help me.

Comment: Thanks for the update. And which values are the ones you would want to save for a subsequent run?

Comment: A simple workaround would be to save the JSON output from `curl` to a JSON file and ... I dunno, check if it's less than 24 hours old and reuse the same values if it is?

Comment: There are either 2 or 3 values I need to save. The first two are essential and the third is optional if it exists. Value 1 is the first (and possibly only) URL modifier such as `'freedesktop/pkg-config'`, value 2 is which function to pass the arguments to the first time such as `git_1_fn or git_2_fn`, the third is a secondary URL modifier IF it exists such at `'T' ` . The values in total will look like this as is posted in my example `'freedesktop/pkg-config' '1' 'T'`. The `'1'` value tells the script to pass to the function `git_1_fn`

Comment: Saving the JSON is an interesting idea. Thanks for that.